# Mongo E11000 duplicate key error collection after mongo 3.4 to 3.6 upgrade

Tags: database, mongodb, database-administration

I have a Mongo replica set on Ubuntu with three members configured for my information system and am having issues when I try to upgrade MongoDB from version 3.4 to 3.6

After setting the `featureCompatibilityVersion` to 3.4 on the master node and checking it on the two slaves, I started upgrading the slaves one by one (I gracefully shut the DB down with `db.shutdownServer()`, update the packages using apt and start the mongod service). That all went fine and the slaves transitioned back to secondary states. I then shut the master down, repeated all the steps for the upgrade from the official guide (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.6-upgrade-replica-set/) and tried starting the mongod service again.

However, while I was upgrading the master node, the slave that was elected as a new master crashed with the error:

> [rsSync] Fatal assertion 40454 DuplicateKey: E11000 duplicate key error collection: admin.system.users index: user_1_db_1 dup key: { : "john", : "admin" } at src/mongo/db/system_index.cpp 134

I didn't notice this and when the old master started up again it too crashed with the same error. In my frantic trying to get the members up again, the third member had also been elected as a master for a short time before crashing with the same error.

When I managed to get the first member up again as a standalone, I checked the `system.users` collection and found that there were indeed two users with the same username for the admin database (I redacted the parts with ...):

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5...8"), "user" : "john", "db" : "admin", "credentials" : { "MONGODB-CR" : "f...c" }, "roles" : [ { "role" : "read", "db" : "admin" } ] }
```

and

```
{ "_id" : "admin.john", "user" : "john", "db" : "admin", "credentials" : { "MONGODB-CR" : "f...c" }, "roles" : [ { "role" : "read", "db" : "admin" } ] }
```

My question is how is that possible? Shouldn't mongo prevent someone from adding an identical user? Or did mongo try to change that collection after the upgrade and failed? I am using authSchema version 3 if it makes any difference. Thanks!

Comment: Although the two users are indeed duplicates, their `_id` are different which suggests that the two users were created using different methods somehow. I'm not sure why the duplicate was not caught by the unique index earlier, but they appear to be old pre-3.0 users (still using the removed `MONGODB-CR` auth schema). I think during the 2.6->3.0 upgrade, you haven't done the [Upgrade to SCRAM](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.0-scram/) step.

Comment: @kevinadi you are right, I haven't upgraded to SCRAM because I'm using older drivers and had some compatibility issues with it. However, according to Mongo docs, version 3.6 still supports the MONGODB-CR mechanism (it's dropped in 4.0 afaik). That's why I mentioned that the authSchema version is 3. Any idea why Mongo allowed duplicate entries to exist? I tried to replicate the issue but I get an error (user already exists) no matter if I try db.createUser() or restoring an admin db dump which contains the duplicates using mongorestore.

Comment: Honestly I don't know how it can be allowed unless the unique index was dropped for some reason in the original deployment. If you still have access to the original servers, could you execute `db.system.users.getIndexes()` in the `admin` database?